# force load if dynamically inserted script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically insert a script tag into the `.inner-booking-wrap` element which will then load a booking form.  Although the method I've used below is hit and miss, it'll insert the tag but won't always run the script, I've never tried it inside a timeout to delay it a little.

```
$('<script>').attr('src', 'URL_GOES_HERE').appendTo('#booking-form .inner-booking-wrap');
```

Is there anyway of doing what I've done above with some sort of force load of said script after it's been appended?

Comment: The script is looking odd - there is no closing tag. Is there any errors in console?

Comment: @andrey.shedko the closing tag gets added automatically so that isn't the issue, no errors in console no, just very hit and miss as to whether the script will run or not

Comment: I've done sth like that with pure JavaScript. Jquery way didnt worked for me. I'll post you and answer in few.

Comment: I think problem in loaded script, may be code written inside `$(document).ready(....)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try pure JS:

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    (function() {
                        var parentElement = document.querySelector("head");
                        var theFirstChild = parentElement.firstChild;
                        var ga = document.createElement("script");
                        ga.type = "text/javascript";
                        ga.src = "url_here";
                        parentElement.insertBefore(ga, theFirstChild);
                    })();
                </script>
```

Comment: the only problem I foresee with this is that I need the script tag to go within the `.inner-booking-wrap` element (as per my code) as this is where the booking form will be place. So not in the head, is this possible too?

Comment: I've just tested this and still having problems, it either isn't inserting the script at all or not loading it?

Comment: You might wanna try `eval()`, but it got security issues. [Eval docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)